# How do I intercept if a tracking request was made by GTM (Google tag manager)?

Tags: google-tag-manager

There are many ways advertisers can make a tracking request to my server (Ad domain), including

- direct calls using JavaScript,
- Image tags,
- using Tag managers like GTM (Google tag manager)

How can I distinguish which requests are coming from Google Tag manager? Do they provide any APIs or mechanism?

Alternates tried:

- Google gives a feature to add variables. And I could force-add a variable to the tracking request. The presence of that variable (regardless of its value) could be one way to figure this out.

Challenge:

- this requires Advertisers to redo their setup. How can I intercept without them having to do anything, like reconfiguring the URL to add page variables.

Answer (score 0):

GTM is just a way to deploy Javascript. There is not "default" way of figuring out if the JS was deployed via GTM.

However you could rewrite your code to check for the existence of certain variables (such as `window.google_tag_manager`) to at least ascertain if GTM is installed on a site (by then it is a pretty good guess that your tag is deployed via GTM) and  have it add a variable in the destination url.

Comment: This is great. Working on such a technique already. Is there a way to understand if the advertiser is hitting my URL **without** my script (for eg., using an Image element via GTM)? Thanks for answering the question.